# The closure of $\mathbb{N}$ is $\mathbb N$. The closure of $\mathbb Z$ is $\mathbb Z$... etc

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Prove this lemma

Lemma: The closure of $\mathbb{N}$ is $\mathbb N$. The closure of $\mathbb Z$ is $\mathbb Z$. The closure of $\mathbb Q$ is $\mathbb R$, and the closure of $\mathbb R$ is $\mathbb R$. The closure of the empty set is the empty set.

### My Attempt

1) The closure of $\mathbb N$ is $\mathbb N$: Let $x\in \bar{N}$ such that $\epsilon >0$, then there exists $n\in N$ such that $|n-x| \leq \epsilon$. Let $\epsilon = 1/4$. Then $|n-x|<1/4$ <=> $x-1/4 \leq n \leq x+1/4$.

Not sure where to go from here

Comment: You should be more clear about what kind of closure you're discussing. Closure in the Euclidean topology on $\Bbb{R}$ apparently, but you should state that.

Comment: If you're not sure where to go from there, then why did you pick $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{4}$? Thinking about that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hint: what is the compliment of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @CliveNewstead I can choose another $\epsilon$ and another $n_2$ to show that $n_1=n_2$. So $\epsilon = 0$ => $x=n$. Now how to prove for Q and R?

Comment: @Bonnaduck $\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: Not quite. Surely it excludes $\{1,2,3,...\}$. So it must be $(-\infty,1)\cup(1,2)\cup(2,3)\cup\dots$. So clearly, it's compliment is open. What does that make $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Your last statement that $ x-1/4 \leq n \leq x+1/4$ is the same as $-1/4 \leq n-x \leq 1/4$ and you know $n-x$ is a natural number. Conclude.

Comment: ... the $-1/4 < n - x < 1/4$.  Let $\epsilon_2 = |n - x|< 1/4$ if $\epsilon_2 = 0$ $x = n$.  Other wise there exist another $n_1$ so that $|x -n_1| < |x - n|$ so $n_1 \ne n$ and $|n_1 - n| \le |n_1 - x| + |n - x| < 1/4 + 1/4 = 1/2$.  So there are two natural numbers that are less than 1/2 apart.  Which is impossible.   So $|x -n| = 0$ and $x \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: I think i got it with the Q and R. But how to show the empty set now?

Comment: What are the limit points of the empty set?  Which points in R are such that every neighborhood contains a member of the empty set?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easier method:

If $\mathbb N$ has no limit points than $\mathbb N$ is by definition vacuously closed and by definition  $\overline {\mathbb N} = \mathbb N \cup \text{limit Points}(\mathbb N) = \mathbb N$.

Let $x$ by a real limit point of $\mathbb N$, if any exist.  There exists an integer $n$ such that $n \le x < n+1$.  If $n = x$ then there is no other integer in the interval $(n-1, n + 1)$ other than $n = x$ so $x$ is not a limit point.  So $x$, if it exists, is not an integer and $n < x < n+1$.  Let $\epsilon = \min(x -n, n+1 - x)$.  Then $(x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon) \subseteq (n, n+1)$ and this interval contains no natural numbers.  So $x$ is *NOT* a limit point of $\mathbb N$.

So $\mathbb N$ has no limit points.  So $\mathbb N$ is closed.

Same argument of $\mathbb Z$.

To prove $\overline {\mathbb Q} = \mathbb R$.  Let $x \in \mathbb R$.  Let $\{q_n\}$ be a cauchy sequency of rational numbers converging to $x$.  For every $\epsilon$ there exists and $q_i$ s.t. $d(x,q_i) < \epsilon$ so $x$ is a limit point of $\mathbb Q$.

To prove $\overline {\mathbb R} = \mathbb R$ is... obvious.  Let $x \in \mathbb R$, $\epsilon > 0$ and $y = x - \epsilon/2$, then $d(x,y) = \epsilon/2 < \epsilon$. So $x$ is a limit point.

Closure of the empty set is the empty set.... well, as the empty set has no elements, no elements exists in any neighborhood of any point so no point is a limit point of the empty set.  The empty set has not limit points.