# The closure of $\mathbb{N}$ is $\mathbb N$. The closure of $\mathbb Z$ is $\mathbb Z$. The closure of $\mathbb Q$ is $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

> The closure of $\mathbb{N}$ is $\mathbb N$. The closure of $\mathbb Z$ is $\mathbb Z$. The closure of $\mathbb Q$ is $\mathbb R$, and the closure of $\mathbb R$ is $\mathbb R$. The closure of the empty set is the empty set. 
>   Note there is a similar question in [The closure of $\mathbb{N}$ is $\mathbb N$. The closure of $\mathbb Z$ is $\mathbb Z$... etc](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1770515/the-closure-of-mathbbn-is-mathbb-n-the-closure-of-mathbb-z-is-math) however, I would like to get the answer to this question without the usage of limit points, sequences, convergence and things like that.

Mainly I want to get the answer by using the definition of adherent points because at this point in the book only it was stated.

The closure of $\mathbb{N}$ is $\mathbb{N}$. Let $\bar{X}$ be the closure of $\mathbb{N}$. We know that for any $n \in N$, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $m \in N$, namely $m=n$ such that $|n-m| < \epsilon$. So, $\mathbb{N} \subset \bar{X}$. Now I should show that there does not exists any $x \in \bar{X}\setminus{N}$ such that for any positive $\epsilon_0 > 0$ there exists an $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x - m| < \epsilon_0$. Now if $|x - m| < \epsilon_0$ for every positive $\epsilon_0$ then by definition (as far as I recall) $x = m$, if $m \in \mathbb{N}$ but this can not be true since then $x \in \mathbb{N}$ too. So we got a contradiction.

For $\mathbb{Z}$ it should work out the same way, shouldn't it?

For $\mathbb{Q}$. We know that for any $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ it is true that $r<q<u$, for some $r,u \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $x \in \bar{X}$ the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$. Then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $q \in Q$ such that $|x-q| < \epsilon$. However, we also know that $|x-q| > |x-r|$, so we would get a contradiction unless $x = r$ (yes?). Therefore, $\bar{X} \subset \mathbb{R}$. Conversley, if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $|x-q| < \epsilon$ (Which is not true!).

The closure of the empty set is the empty set: We say that $x$ is adherent to the subset of $\mathbb{R}$ if for any positive $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $y$ in the subset such that $|x-y| < \epsilon$. However, since no such $y$ exists for the empty set then the closure of the empty set is the empty set.

Comment: The term "closure" **does not** apply to a single space. It applies to a pair (space, subspace). The closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ is indeed $\mathbb{Q}$, not $\mathbb{R}$. It is $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. While the closure of $\mathbb{R}$ in, say the sphere $S^1$ is $S^1$, not $\mathbb{R}$. Only the closure of the empty set is the empty set regardles of the overlying space (because the empty set is closed in any topology by definition).

Comment: @freakish In the book that I am using (Terence Tao Analysis 1) the closure is defined as a set of all the adherent points of $X$, where $X$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You always know that $A \subseteq \overline{A}$, so for the first two you must concentrate on points *not* in $\Bbb N$ or $\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

We're working in the ambient space $\Bbb R$, I assume.

To see that the closure of $\Bbb N$ is $\Bbb N$ we need to show that **any** $x \notin \Bbb N$ is **not** an adherent point of $\Bbb N$. Well any $x \in \Bbb R$ we can write uniquely as $n + x'$ where $n \in \Bbb Z$ (the *integer part* of $x$) and $x' \in [0,1)$, the *fractional part* of $x$. Now, if $x \notin \Bbb N$ then either $x <0$ (and then the open neighbourhood $(-\infty,0)$ shows $x$ is not an adherent point of $\Bbb N$) or $x>0$ and $x'>0$. But then $(x-x'', x+x'')$ where $x''=\min(x', 1-x')>0$ is disjoint from $\Bbb N$ and shows that $x$ is then also not an adherent point of $\Bbb N$.

For $\Bbb Z$ we just use the last part of the argument we used for $\Bbb N$.

To see that the closure of $\Bbb Q$ equals $\Bbb R$, take any $x \in \Bbb R$ and $(y,z)$ any basic open neighbourhood of $x$. Then by standard facts about $\Bbb Q$ there must be a rational $q$ with $y < q < x$ and this shows that $(y,z) \cap \Bbb Q \neq \emptyset$. So $x$ is an adherent point of $\Bbb Q$ and as $x$ was arbitrary, the closure of the rationals equals the whole space $\Bbb R$.

There cannot be any adherent points for the empty set, as this set is disjoint from any neighbourhood of any point. So $\overline{\emptyset}=\emptyset$.